# time span in a black hole vs earth

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation

This is a thought experiment:  I am an immortal and I live for  1 billion years on earth.  My identical twin brother spends the same amount of time in/on a black hole.  To him, did he spend exactly 1 billion years in/on that black hole, or longer or shorter, and by how many years.  If you want to do some calculations, let us say that this black hole has a mass of 100 suns.  Don't tell me that he can not live in a black hole.

Comment: FWIW he can not live in a black hole. But the time he spent there was shorter. In fact, time dilates so much near a black hole, I'd be surprised if he had even entered it by the end of your billion years. But, we won't do the math for you. That's outside the purview of this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its impossible to answer a thought experiment that is not even possible in principle.

Answer (score 1):

(as usual, we assume the static black hole solution for simplicity).

If hovering outside the horizon, the gravitational time dilation goes to infinity as the distance from the horizon goes to zero.

The elapsed proper time of the twin hovering outside the event horizon is given by

$$\Delta \tau = \Delta t \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}} = 10^9 \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}}\; \mathrm{years}$$

which can be made arbitrarily small ($r_s$ is the [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius)).

The twin can, in principle, hover at a fixed Schwarzschild coordinate $r > r_s$ from the black hole however, the twin cannot hover 'on' or within the horizon located at $r = r_s$.

> Don't tell me that he can not live in a black hole.

He won't live for long.

Once within the horizon, the twin must encounter the singularity within a finite proper time which, even for a supermassive black hole, is relatively short - no more than about 4.2 hours for a 1 billion solar mass black hole.

Answer (score 0):

A brief intuitive answer.    Black holes are enormously difficult to work with, the warped space and tidal forces are enormous, but I think you want to ignore the difficulties.

A black hole with 100 solar masses would have a radius of about 300 KM, if you put it next to the Earth, it would be a bit smaller than Texas.   Lets say your friend's ship orbits at about 1 meter above the event horizon, which would require an enormous energy expenditure as a standard orbit wouldn't do you any good there, so he'd experience enormous gravitational forces and tidal forces, probably sufficient to turn the hardest metal into dust, but lets ignore that.

1 meter above the event horizon is 300,001 meters above the center of mass.   Using Alfred Centauri's formula

(1-(300,000/300,001)^.5 = .00182 or about 1/547.    So at 1 meter above the black hole, he would age 1 year for every 547 years you age.

At 1 CM above, or 100 times closer, the time dilation works out to about 10 times greater.   Basically the square root of the reduction of distance.

There's a problem though.   lets say your friend is 2 meters tall, then his feet are 1 meter from the event horizon but his head is 3 meters from the event horizon (He'd have to be very strong to even survive that, but we're ignoring that), then his feet would age slower than his head and that might confuse his circulatory system, in addition to the other difficulties he'd face.   The ratio, 1 meter above to 3 meters above would be the square root of 3, so the time dilation head to toe wouldn't be huge, but it would be enough to be confusing.   The ship would likely have near light speed velocity as well to help maintain it's orbit, so there would be time dilation too, but it gets kinda complicated to calculate both in conjunction.

Now if he was on the surface of the event horizon, which is hard to imagine cause just a centimeter above the time dilation is 5,470 times normal but on the event horizon it's pretty much infinite and below it, it's . . . who knows.

Now if it was a super-massive black hole, millions of suns, then the effect isn't quite so pronounced, but with a stellar mass black hole, every centimeter has a measurably different time dilation, so saying what time a person would see gets a little imprecise.   Saying what time a single particle would see is more reasonable.

But the quick answer to your question is that he would age much slower than you.   Your billion years would be much less time to him.